# What properties does a rank-$1$ matrix have?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, rank-1-matrices

I have seen a lot of papers mentioning that a certain matrix is rank-$1$. What properties does a rank-$1$ matrix have?

I know that if a matrix is rank-$1$ then there are no independent columns or rows in that matrix.

Comment: The section "Properties" at (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra) gives a good account of the properties (e.g., Sylvester's rank inequality).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any rank one matrix $A$ can always be written $A=xy^\intercal$ for vectors $x$ and $y$. More precisely...

> **Proposition**: A matrix in $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ has rank one if and only if it can be written as the outer product of two nonzero
>   vectors in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ (i.e., $A=xy^{\intercal}$).

*Proof*. This follows from the observation
$$
\begin{pmatrix}x_{1}y^{\intercal}\\
x_{2}y^{\intercal}\\
\vdots\\
x_{n}y^{\intercal}
\end{pmatrix}=xy^{\intercal}=\begin{pmatrix}y_{1}x & y_{2}x & \cdots & y_{n}x\end{pmatrix}.
$$

> **Corollary**: The eigenspace of a rank one matrix in $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is one dimensional.

*Proof*. If $A$ is a rank one matrix in $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, the previous result tells us that it can be written in the form $A=xy^{\intercal}$. Next, note that for any vector $w$ in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, 
$$
Aw=(xy^{\intercal})w=(y^{\intercal}w)x.
$$
Since $(y^{\intercal}w)$ is a scalar, it follows that if $w$ is
an eigenvector of $A$, it must be a multiple of $x$. In other words,
the eigenspace of $A$ is
$$
\operatorname{span}(x)=\left\{ \alpha x\colon\alpha\in\mathbb{C}\right\} .
$$

Comment: Is there also a geometric interpretation of the linear transformation associated with $A = xy^T$?

Comment: @philmcole: according to the answer, $Aw$ is always a scalar multiple of the vector $x$. The scalar multiple depends on the length of $y$ and $w$ and the angle between them (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

Comment: Does the transpose change to conjugate transpose in case of C